# why the data in the xlsx document I read by read_excel() is inconsistent with the original data in R?

Tags: r

I have a test excel document, there is a column in the document, the content is

```
NO
0.506
0.494
3.107
0.726
0.371
```

I read this excel document through readxl::read_excel("myexcel.xlsx", sheet = "mysheet"), but the result is

```
NO
0.50600000000000001
0.49399999999999999
3.1070000000000002
0.72599999999999998
0.371
```

Why the data I read is inconsistent with the original data with the excel document?

Comment: When you expand the decimals in Excel to 15-20 decimals or so, do do you get the same results as when you read in the Excel file in R? It seems like Excel is rounding the numbers to 3 decimal places whereas R is not.

Comment: The original number in my excel document has only three digits, and no rounding is done.

Comment: In order for this to be really reproducible we probably (unfortunately) need a link to your Excel sheet, or at least the bit of it with these values in it.

Comment: Run `options(digits = 3)` in the R console.